# Xcode 6.0 crashes when trying to open .xib file from previous versions

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6, xcode6gm

I am using Xcode version 6.0. When i try to open .xib file xcode crashes.
In previous version of Xcode i.e Xcode 5.1 or 5.1.1 it was working fine.

Error is:

```
dyld: problem loading iOS simulator dyld
2014-09-15 17:31:07.823 ibtoold[1971:507] Init failed: Error Domain=IBMessageChannelErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder" UserInfo=0x7f8f32db6560 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to communicate with Interface Builder, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool crashed: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP), IBCrashLog=

Dyld Error Message:
  problem loading iOS simulator dyld
}
2014-09-15 17:31:07.824 ibtoold[1971:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-6245/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBAbstractMessageChannelInterfaceBuilderToolManager.m:76
Details:  Failed to attach to Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool with error: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo=0x7f8f32daaab0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8f32db65f0 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder", NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (2314) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.



Dyld Error Message:
  problem loading iOS simulator dyld
}
Object:   <IBCocoaTouchToolManager: 0x7f8f306aa620>
Method:   -attachToToolForTargetRuntime:isForLiveViews:scaleFactor:assertOnFailureToAttach:assertOnPostLaunchRequestFailures:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8f3041caf0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2014-09-15 17:31:08.352 ibtoold[1971:507] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-6238/InterfaceBuilder/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:45
Details:  Failed to launch Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool: Error Domain=com.apple.InterfaceBuilder Code=-1 "Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool." UserInfo=0x7f8f32daaab0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8f32db65f0 "Failed to communicate with Interface Builder", NSLocalizedDescription=Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" for further information., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool (2314) failed to launch and exited with status (null), signal 5.



Dyld Error Message:
  problem loading iOS simulator dyld
}
Object:   <NSThread: 0x7f8f3041caf0>
Method:   -cocoaTouchToolForTargetRuntime:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f8f3041caf0>{name = (null), num = 1}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001056a215a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x00000001056a1baf _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001056a1e9e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010b849157 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  4  0x000000010b848eb9 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshallerWithContext (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  5  0x000000010b848d89 IBAskClassInTargetRuntimeForValueForKeyPathUsingResultMarshaller (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  6  0x000000010b87b04f (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  7  0x000000010b87b3f2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  8  0x000000010b87b607 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
  9  0x000000010b849876 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 10  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x00007fff8e65b512 -[NSImage initWithCoder:] (in AppKit)
 15  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x00007fff8e7da506 +[NSPatternColor newWithCoder:zone:] (in AppKit)
 20  0x00007fff8e41f582 -[NSColor initWithCoder:] (in AppKit)
 21  0x000000010b84967d (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 22  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 23  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 24  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 25  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 26  0x000000010b9670d8 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 27  0x000000010b99bfd7 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 28  0x000000010b9221d6 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 29  0x000000010b963e12 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
 30  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 31  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 32  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 33  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 34  0x00000001067ba282 __48-[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 35  0x00000001067b6403 -[IBXMLDecoderAbstractObjectElement enumerateElements:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 36  0x00000001067ba20b -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 37  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 38  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 39  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 40  0x000000010669506b -[IBObjectRecord initWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 41  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 42  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 43  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 44  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 45  0x00000001067ba282 __48-[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 46  0x00000001067b6403 -[IBXMLDecoderAbstractObjectElement enumerateElements:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 47  0x00000001067ba20b -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeArray:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 48  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 49  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 50  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 51  0x000000010554a74c -[DVTMutableOrderedSet initWithCoder:] (in DVTFoundation)
 52  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 53  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 54  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 55  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 56  0x000000010665fad7 -[IBObjectContainer decodeObjectsWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 57  0x0000000106661a24 -[IBObjectContainer initWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 58  0x00000001067ba6fc -[IBXMLDecoder deserializeObject:fromXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 59  0x00000001067bb4b2 __36-[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 60  0x00000001067bb10f -[IBXMLDecoder invokeRestoringDecodingStack:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 61  0x00000001067bb2b9 -[IBXMLDecoder objectForXMLElement:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 62  0x00000001064ca38e -[IBDocument decodeDocumentWithCoder:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 63  0x00000001064caeaf -[IBDocument decodeContentsOfURL:ofType:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 64  0x00000001064c53d9 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 65  0x0000000106523080 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager doNotSynchronouslyComputeAutolayoutStatusWhilePerformingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 66  0x00000001064c5231 __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 67  0x00000001064fa69b -[IBDocument invokeWithUndoSuppressed:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 68  0x00000001064c4ee9 -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 69  0x00000001054ab1c1 (in ibtoold)
 70  0x00000001054a632f (in ibtoold)
 71  0x00000001054acfe1 (in ibtoold)
 72  0x00000001054b24c7 (in ibtoold)
 73  0x00000001054b2a17 (in ibtoold)
 74  0x00000001054b28e7 (in ibtoold)
 75  0x00000001054a249f (in ibtoold)
 76  0x00000001054b20b1 (in ibtoold)
 77  0x00000001054b1308 (in ibtoold)
 78  0x00007fff8c07e5fd start (in libdyld.dylib)
 79  0x0000000000000002
Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Can't getting solution. I will appreciate any ideas and thoughts!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the error that Xcode crashes with?

Comment: Hi wjl..Please see my updated question above.

Comment: In what directory have you installed/copied the Xcode 6 executable to?  It should be under the /Applications directory.

Comment: It doesn't need to be in /Applications, although running it off the DMG might cause issues. @Tejas if you install Xcode rather than run from the disk image does that fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks mmccomb... Your solutions works. Yes @wjl xcode installation fix my problem.

Comment: Awesome! Feel free to type that down in the answer field so you can self-accept and mark the question as closed.

Comment: Hi All @TejasBharambe - please could you explain an in-depth the answer here? I'm having the exact same issue and I've not been able to find a fix. I've got Xcode 6.0.1 installed in the applications directory from the Mac App Store download. It always hangs upon opening. The same applies for 6.1. I've got 5.1 which does work. I have uninstalled 5.1 and reinstalled 6.0.1 with the same issue. Any guidance on this would be a life saver. Also, how are you obtaining the error above? I want to see if I'm getting the same issue in the form of the Error.

Answer (score 4):

I was suffered with same problem i resolved this problem by replace .xib file by the latest updated .xib and clean & build again this problem is relosved.

Answer (score 0):

Same error encountered while I was working with XCode 6.4 version and OS X 10.10.5.

I dont know how? and why? But I tried and searched alot for answer to resolve but I haven't found solution.

In developer forum someone answered "by restoring OS version that will remove error".

But in my case I have re installed XCode, opened the project and cleaned it. That error disappeared. This might not be a right solution but it saved my time by just re installing instead of searching for right solution. It may be helpful for someone.